# How can I write a function to convert sql query to a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

With lot of struggle I somehow written a function that fetches tables and data in the table, but got paused while converting the query to DataFrame, Any help guys!!

I have tried this way, any suggestions are welcome and I would learn from them!!

```
    import pandas as pd,pymysql.cursors

    class Db_Conn(object):

        def __init__(self):
            connection=pymysql.connect(host='****',
                                       user='****',
                                       password='*****',
                                       db='******',
                                       charset='utf8mb4',
                                       cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            self.connection=connection

        def fetchtables(self,query):
            with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
                if cursor.execute(query):
                    for (table_name) in cursor:
                        print(table_name)
                elif cursor.execute(query):
                    a=cursor.fetchall()
                    print(a)
```

I struggled with this...which i want this function to convert sql query to DataFrame

```
    def dataframes(self,query):
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        a=pd.read_sql(query,cursor)
        print(a)
```

I have created the object as:

```
db1=Db_Conn()
# db2=db1.fetchtables('show tables')
# db3=db1.fetchtables('select * from **')
df1=db1.dataframes('select * from ****')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use like below `read_sql()`

```
def _get_data(self):

    df= pd.read_sql("select col1,col2 from table_name", connection)
    return df
```

It will return dataframe

Comment: How can I write this in a function as I have dataframes()?

Comment: may i know how to create reference for this ? I mean db1._get_data(query)? or any other way

Comment: @Codenewbie does not understand what you mean?

Comment: Here what is db_connection , because i didn't use such thing sorry

Comment: db_connection=your connection string for database connection

Comment: NameError: name 'db_connection' is not defined.........should I have to import anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197383/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-codenewbie).

Comment: I tried this way with your idea and it works !! thanks mate
    'def _get_data(self,query):
        df = pd.read_sql(query,self.connection)
        return df'

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=your_server_name;Database=your_db_name;")
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Orders',cnxn)
```